# Save search results into JTable

Tags: java, swing, httpurlconnection

//I try to make an function for catching all results of search of some string, //but I only catching one element and my for does not continue to all results of //my search.
//There is an error in my loop sequence?
//Do you have any soggestion?

//This is my code.
//Sorry my code it is in spanish.

```
private void Buscar(String tema){
    String url = "http://www.google.com/search?q="+tema;
    String resultado;
    String[] resultados;
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jT_ResultadosBusqueda.getModel();
    int contacampos;
    try{
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((tema = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(tema);
    }
    in.close();
    resultado = response.toString();
    resultados = resultado.split("<a href=\"/url?q=");
    contacampos = 1;
    do{
        for (int i = 0; i < resultados.length; i++) {
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,i);
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,resultados.length);
            int inicio = resultados[i].indexOf("\"http");
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,inicio);
            int fondo = resultados[i].indexOf("\">");
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,fondo);
            String result = resultados[i].substring(inicio + 1, fondo);
            model.addRow(new Object[]{result,"Ejemplo1","Tema1","Asunto1","www.1.com"});
        }
                        contacampos = contacampos +1;
    }while(contacampos<resultados.length);          

    }catch(HeadlessException | IOException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e.getMessage (),"¡Aviso!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of trying to reinvent the wheel, perhaps have a look at some of the available parses, like [jsoup](https://jsoup.org)

Comment: I will check the JSoup. Thanks for your help in this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution it was Jsoup.

This is my actual code.

```
private void Buscar(String tema){
        try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com/search?q="+tema).get();
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jT_ResultadosBusqueda.getModel();
            //doc.title()
            Elements link = doc.select("a[href]");
            for (Element linkline : link) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,linkline);
                model.addRow(new Object[]{linkline.tagName(),linkline.id(),"","",""});
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Buscador.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```